# Storing information and retrieving it in javascript in a function with button

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

i am have made a button, and everytime i click it it takes a value from my input box, and it subtracts it and stores it back into the input box value. but what i am trying to do is, store my value into an array or anything everything my button is clicked.

so for example i want to do this,
balance = 100
button is clicked
balance is now 90
and i want
array[0] to have 100
array[1] to have 90
and everytime i want it to continue to append to the array but when i enter my button.

i have tried many things and everytime it always stores the value into array [0] and over writes it

```
var clicktotal=0;
var array = [];
function myfunc(){
var Bal = document.getElementById("Bank_Balance");
var Balance = Bal.value
array[clicktotal]=Balance;
console.log(clicktotal+"My array click total "+array[clicktotal]);
}
clicktotal++;
```

see i have this and there are some other things in the function, but the console.log is alway giving me the same number without incrimenting my variable, so it is still overwriting my array.

where my button looks like this

```
<input type="button" id="buy_things" value="Buy" style="width:55px; height:33px; color:#938CDD;" >
```

and my init function is

```
var Buy_button = document.getElementById("buy_things");
                Buy_button.addEventListener ('click', myfunc ,true);
```

if there are any idea, im open to anything, i have tried using arrays, local storage, and objects but i cant seem to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to `push` items onto the array:

```
array.push(Bal.value);
```

Your `myfunc` rewritten:

```
function myfunc(){
    var Bal = document.getElementById("Bank_Balance");
    array.push(Bal.value);
    console.log(array.length, "My array click total "+ Bal.value);
}
```

I realize my rewritten example above doesn't use `clicktotal`, but your example above did not use it correctly. You declared the `clicktotal` variable with a value of 0, and you only increment it once. Each time `myfunc` is called, it does not increment `clicktotal`, so it stays as 1, despite how many times `myfunc` is called.

Comment: AWESOME, thanks ive been stuck on this for a while now, thanks!! but is there anyway to get the values from this array and use the same values in another function? i need to use the same values and validate it to check if it is the same before letting the user sell the item.